# Why does QT program crash upon SDL startup (C4Droid)

Tags: c++, qt, sdl-2

I'm trying to wrap an SDL2 game I wrote within a QT app, for GUI controls; I'm following an example from GitHub, however it crashes. I've reduced it to find that SDL_Init causes this. Since I'm unable to see console output on C4Droid, I'm limited in my ability to debug this. Here is the minimal example:

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include "SDLWin.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) <  0)
    {
        printf("SDL failed to initialize: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
    
    SDLWin win;
    win.show();
    
    int retval = app.exec();
    
    SDL_Quit();
    
    return retval;
}
```

The SDLWin class is now a trivial shell, servng as a generic QMainWindow, as simply initializing SDL is what causes the crash.

SDLWin.hpp:

```cpp
#ifndef SDLWIN_HPP
#define SDLWIN_HPP

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>


class SDLWin : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    
    SDLWin();
    ~SDLWin();
    
    void SDLInit();
private:
    QWidget      *main_win;
};

#endif
```

SDLWin.cpp:

```cpp
#include "SDLWin.hpp"
#include <QWidget>

SDLWin::SDLWin() : main_win(new QWidget)
{
    setWindowTitle("tetris");
    setCentralWidget(main_win);
}
SDLWin::~SDLWin()
{}
```

application.pro:

```cpp
QT += core uitools widgets gui

HEADERS       = ./src/SDLWin.hpp
SOURCES       = ./src/main.cpp \
                ./src/SDLWin.cpp

MOC_DIR       = ./src/moc
OBJECTS_DIR   = ./src/objects
RCC_DIR       = ./src/resource

LIBS += -lSDL2main \
        -lSDL2 \
        -lSDL2_image \
        -lSDL2_ttf \
        -lSDL2_mixer

#! [0]
RESOURCES     = application.qrc
#! [0]

# install
target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES]/widgets/mainwindows/application
INSTALLS += target

simulator: warning(This example might not fully work on Simulator platform)
```